# save where clause in a variable and use it in laravel query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have saved all of my where clause in a variable and i'm trying to join that variable inside laravel query but its not working. Here is mine code

```
$where .= "";
$where .= '->where("product_details.title", '.$request->title.')'; 
$where .= '->where("product_details.id", '.$request->id.')'; 
$results = DB::table('product_details').'$where'.->get();
```

How to use variable inside query?

Comment: Is your query dynamic? If not, why are you doing this? Also, have you tried running this? Is so what errors do you get?

Comment: yes it is dynamic and error i get is "syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)"

Answer (score 3):

you can used like that by using **if condition statement** for dynamic query

```
$results = DB::table('product_details')

if($request->title) {
   $results->where("product_details.title", $request->title);
}
if($request->id) {
   $results->where("product_details.id", $request->id);
}
$result->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you want to do this. The following should just work.

```
DB::table('product_details')
    ->where([
        'product_details.title' => $request->title
        'product_details.id' => $request->id
    ])
    ->get();
```

Now, let's say that you may not always have a title or id from the request, you could also do this

```
DB::table('product_details')
    ->when($request->title, function ($query, $title) {
        return $query->where('product_details.title', $title);
    })
    ->when($request->id, function ($query, $id) {
        return $query->where('product_details.id', $id);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: i'm using $where variable because i'm working on filters and i don't want to wrote the whole query again

Comment: Not sure what you mean by working on filters? However, if you meant that you may not always have filters present on your request, I updated my query.

Comment: As the where clause accepts an array, could you ot build the array in the dynamic fashion and then put that inside the clause. So ->where($array). This will allow you to build the clause and inject it before the query is ran.

Comment: Sure you could also do that :)

Answer (score 0):

this will not work because you are saving text in string and output will be on string you need to convert it to [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) Try This.

```
$results = DB::table('product_details')  . eval ($where) .->get();
```

Comment: i got this error "syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)"

Comment: eval showing you converted output try to dd and test what's result saving $where

Comment: output of dd($where) is:
"->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET(?, product_details.industry_id)", [4,5])->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET(?, product_details.product_category_id)", [1,2]) ◀"

Comment: If you have to use `eval` it's most likely that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Using eval is really a bad practice but the correct form would be like $results = eval ('DB::table('product_details')' . $where . '->get()');